# How is EOF generated and interpreted in c based languages?

Tags: c, eof

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int c, nl=0;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if(c=='\n')
            nl++;
                
    printf("%d",nl+1);
    return 0;
}
```

On Ubuntu 18.04, GCC 7.3.0

There's no output on console when the `getchar()` comparison is made with `EOF`. it works fine with other characters. Using `CTRL^D` exits the program with 'code 0' without any output on console. I've tried running it in bash but still no output.

input:

> line 1
>
> line 2
>
> line 3
>
> line 4
>
> line 5

expected output:

> 5

actual output:

> `program exited with code 0`

Comment: Please show the code, input and output and expected output.

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._

Comment: Generating EOF is platform dependent. May be, CTRL^Z ?

Comment: Also, you'd want to use `printf("%d\n", ...)` instead, so that a newline is output after the number.

Comment: I tried running it in cmd on windows...putting ctrl^z exits the application directly. still no output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On *nix systems `EOF` is generated by `Ctrl^D` whereas on Windows system `EOF` is generated by `Ctrl^Z`. I am assuming that you are using Windows system. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file

Answer (score 1):

These programs are meant to read input from file. so on bash if you do this:
        `./linecount < textfile.txt`
will give you the output
         `5`
but i guess in editors using `ctrl^D` to generate/trigger `EOF` character doesn't work well.(At least not on mine).